# Can't get form from a dynamically created form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a button that makes a form appear in my html page. I have a function that gets the data from forms:

```
function getFormData($form){

   var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();

   var indexed_array = {};

   $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){

      indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];

   });

   return indexed_array;
```

}

The function seems to work well because I can get the data from other forms that weren't dynamically created. I create my form this way by clicking a button:

```
var new_form = document.createElement('form');
new_form.id = "new_form";

// (...) all the inputs for the form

// and I append to an existent div 
existent_div.appendChild(new_form);
// and then the inputs
new_form.appendChild(input1); (...)
```

I have another button that should is responsible for getting the form data. It calls this function and in the middle of the function I have this:

```
var new_form_info = getFormData($("#new_form"));
// I get an empty object...
```

Why is this happening? I am not a experienced programmer so sorry for any mistakes...

Comment: You have a syntax error. You should be using `new_form.appendChild(input)`. Check the console it should say that `"append_child"` is not a function

Comment: @synthet1c oh didn't see that. It was a typo. Ty

Comment: What object do you get from selector `$("#new_form")` just before it's passed to `getFormData` function?

Comment: @MarekNaskret I would get this:  "[form#new_form]"

Comment: But do you see those dynamically created fields in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a reason to use the mix of pure js and jquery? JQuery form creating can help you.

```
var new_form = $('<form></form>')
        .attr('id', "new_form")
        .append('<input type="text" value="1" name="inp" />');    
$('#existent_div').append(new_form);
console.log($('#new_form').serializeArray());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yej5xc8s/

**Update**

The mix works too if you append an input and define `existent_div`

```
function getFormData($form){
   var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
   var indexed_array = {};
   $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
      indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
   });

   return indexed_array;
}

var new_form = document.createElement('form');
new_form.id = "new_form";
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.name = "qwer";
input.value = "1";
new_form.appendChild(input);

var existent_div = document.getElementById('existent_div');
existent_div.appendChild(new_form);

console.log(getFormData($("#new_form")));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yej5xc8s/1/